# How to get those elements of a vector, where another vector has '1's at corresponding indices

Tags: c++, stl, vector, indices

I have a two vectors

```
std::vector<int>   markedToBeRead(7);   // contains: 1,1,0,0,1,0,1
std::vector<float> myVec(7);            // contains: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

What is the best way, to get those elements from myVec, where the corresponding indices of `markedToBeRead` have the value `1`.
 Is this possible without the use of a for-loop, but with stl-methods?

```
std::vector<float> myResult;            // contains: 1,2,5,7
```

Thank you!

Comment: Also post whatever have you tried.

Comment: @Potatoswatter presumably they end up in `myResult`.

Comment: Are you stuck with the `vector`, or could you use a `valarray` instead?  If so, you could use the overload of `operator[]` that returns a `masked_array` - this is exactly what you are doing here.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers! I tried exactly this, what @Mohammad suggested in his answer. But I try to find a way without a for-loop, if this is possible. I like to use the STL-own methods. @Björn Pollex I am not stuck with vector. Ok, I will read some help about `masked_array`for `val_array`

Comment: @BjörnPollex and all: What, if `markedToBeRead`would contain the indices explicitly? like `markedToBeRead // contains: 0,1,4,6` ?

Comment: This is also directly supported by valarray.

Answer (score 4):

Clearly a simple for-loop would be very much preferred here rather than any STL algorithm.

But just as a proof of a concept one might adopt stl::equals and a lambda from C++11 here:

```
std::equal(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), markedToBeRead.begin(), [&](float item, int mark)->bool {
    if (mark)
        myResult.push_back(item);
    return true;
});
```

This works, but looks ugly.

Comment: One possible advanage is that this works with any sequences, not just `std::vector`'s

Comment: I disagree (strongly) with the first sentence. A straightforward algorithm is *always* preferred over a loop, it’s simply a higher level of abstraction. But since no straightforward algorithm exists, that point is moot.

Comment: @Konrad: strange, I agree with both your statement (a straightforward algorithm would be preferred over a loop, if one existed), and Gart's statement (a loop would be preferred over any standard algorithm). I don't see any contradiction. As you point out, no standard algorithm is straightforward. The key, I think, is to hide the ugliness (whether it's a loop or a non-straightforward algorithm) inside a function template designed in the style of standard algorithms. Call it `select` or something, and take an output iterator rather than calling `push_back`.

Comment: @Gart: I don't think `std::equal` makes any guarantee about the order of comparisons, does it? The fact that it works on an `InputIterator` is very suggestive, of course, but in theory it could dispatch on the iterator type. I suspect this is one of those cases where it does in fact work everywhere despite not being guaranteed.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Of course, `std::equal` is abused in this example,and I don't know if the OP really needs a strong order guarantee. Yes, theoretically, it may give all the same results but in the wrong order, but practically - higly unlikely

Comment: UPD: We may use `std::mismatch` instead of `std::equal` - I think it has more guarantees about the order of comparisons

Answer (score 3):

Here’s how I’d write an algorithm for this:

```
template <typename I, typename O, typename M>
void mask_copy(I begin, I end, O obegin, M mbegin) {
    for (; begin != end; ++begin, ++mbegin)
        if (*mbegin)
            *obegin++ = *begin;
}
```

Called like this:

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 , 9 };
bool m[] = { true, false, false, false, true, false, false, true, false };

std::vector<int> out;
mask_copy(begin(a), end(a), back_inserter(out), begin(m));
```

(Requires C++11 for `std::begin` and `std::end`.)

That said, a *proper* implementation in a library would probably use `enable_if` (or `static_assert`) to ensure that the iterator types used are compatible with its use, i.e. that `I` is an input iterator, `O` a compatible output iterator, and `M` an input iterator whose `value_type` is `bool`. Unfortunately, lacking concepts this leads to a veritable template ’splosion.

Comment: I like this solution - it is generic and well-defined

Answer (score 2):

something like this?

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < myVec.length(); i++)
    if (markedToBeRead[i] == 1)
        myResult.push_back(myVec[i]);
```

Comment: Simple and straight to the point. I think any answers using standard algorithms will end up less clear than that (even though I usually advocate the use of algorithms instead of explicit loops).

Comment: @Mohammad Thank you for your suggestion. Yes, I precised my question :-). Ok, so will continue using this for-loop suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

In functional terms this is simple: it's a zip of the two input ranges, followed by a filter on the mark being 1, followed by map to extract just the value.

Unfortunately, C++ standard algorithms aren't very well suited to composition. If you don't mind creating intermediary containers, you could apply the binary version of `transform`, followed by `copy_if` (or `remove_copy_if` in C++03, with the predicate reversed, or `remove_if` to modify your intermediary container in place), followed by the unary version of `transform`.

Alternatively, Boost provides the first two operations in the form of iterator adaptors. Something like this (untested):

```
struct marked {
    bool operator()(boost::tuple<int, float> t) {
        return t.get<0>() == 1;
    }
};

auto first = boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(markedToBeRead.begin(), myVec.begin());
auto last = boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(markedToBeRead.end(), myVec.end());

std::transform(
    boost::make_filter_iterator<marked>(first, last),
    boost::make_filter_iterator<marked>(last, last),
    std::back_inserter(myResults);
    [](boost:tuple<int, float> t) { return t.get<1>(); }
);
```

You're probably convinced by now (a) that the loop is better, and (b) that replacing loops with other constructs is something of a spectator sport in C++ ;-)

If you needed to chain further operations, then the `std::transform` can also be replaced by an iterator adaptor: `transform_iterator`.

Comment: In my head, I wanted to do this because I knew how simple it was in Python. After a 15 minute round trip to learn about boost iterator adapters, and then wondering whether `auto` would simplify the code, here it is in front of me. +1

Comment: Incidentally, the great thing about this method is that it is lazy, so the whole filtered range can be passed to a method without additional storage requirements etc.

Comment: @PhilH: Agreed. Why does C++ make `(p[1] for p in zip(markedToBeRead, myVec) if p[0] == 1)` so hard?

Comment: To sift out everyone that hasn't got the stamina.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()  {
        std::vector<int>   markedToBeRead = {  1,1,0,0,1,0,1 };
        std::vector<float> myVec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

        // copy
        std::vector<float> result;
        std::copy_if(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(),
                std::back_inserter(result), [&](const float & f) {
                        return markedToBeRead[&f - &myVec[0]] == 1;
                });

        // Check result
        for (std::vector<float>::size_type i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i)
                std::cout << result[i] << " ";
}
```

[Tested on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/hIUgo)

Comment: Should use `size_t` rather than `unsigned` for the index -- gigantic vectors on 64-bit implementations, and all that.

Comment: Ok, fixed by eliminating the local variable.